# What happens to AsyncTasks after onPause?

Tags: android

I have an AsyncTask that is executed before I move on to the next Activity. Inside this AsyncTask, I have a MediaPlayer.

```
 protected void onPause() {
           stopProgress();
           Log.i(TAG, "onPAUSE");
           try  {
           } finally {
           // If we allocated a player, then cleanup after it
           if (player != null) {
               player.reset();
               player.release();
               player = null;
               Log.d(TAG,"end of player cleanup");
                            }
            }
            super.onPause();
         }
```

Use Scenario:

1. Click play button in Activity 1
2. Move on to Activity 2 before player even loads (log information from onPause is definitely called).
3. While in Activity 2, player from Activity 1 plays when finished loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing should happen to the AsyncTask. It will continue to run. However, this isn't a great way to run a media player in the background (use a service for that). Your code will cancel the media player, but depending on what you have in your AsyncTask, it may still be active. You can ensure that the AsyncTask is killed by calling `cancel (boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` on the task.

If for whatever reason your `MediaPlayer` object is still running using the code above, then call `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` and override `void onCancelled (Result result)` and then kill the `MediaPlayer` from within your thread. Remember, `onCancelled` will only be called AFTER `doInBackground` returns (or you can periodically check `isCancelled()` to see if something has called `cancel()` on your thread. If you set `cancel(true)` then I believe it won't bother waiting for `doInBackground` to finish, but of course that's not as clean.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what you're doing in you AsyncTask, but what ever it is should keep going even it `onPause()` is called. If `onDestroy()` is called and you have your AsyncTask referencing stuff in your Activity, you're going to run into problems though because the AsycnTask will essentially start throwing null pointer exceptions.

Comment: when onDestroy() is called , the async task should be cancelled in it.